# Which application is the docker binary from?

Tags: docker

Is there a way to know if the "docker" binary is the "Docker for Mac" binary or the one from "Docker Toolbox"? Maybe the "docker-machine" binary would have some info about this?

Comment: Don't have any mac to test on but is it possible to work it out from a combination of `docker info` and `docker version`?

Comment: Thanks. Tried it but I only saw a slight version number difference (1.10.2 and 1.10.3). It would be too hard to rely on.

Answer (score 0):

I'm just going to run ls -al on the docker binary and see if it's a link that contains group.com.docker. This would mean it's in the Group Containers directory instead of an actual binary.